# Are we not allowed to use reflexive pronouns to refer to their fellow objects?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know whether the following sentence is ambiguous or not in a way that "himself" could either refer to "the man" or "the boy":

"The man told the boy different things about himself."

I'm thinking that I should use "him" to refer to "the boy" and that "himself" could only refer to "the man" since I've read that reflexive pronouns could only refer to their antecedent subjects, but I'm not quite sure about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a rule when you write or when you answer exam questions, but the problem is that the reader isn't likely to know the rules (or have confidence that you've followed them).  So this is just plain ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Xanne. I also agree that ambiguity may ensue among my readers/listeners after having read/heard this sentence because the rules governing the proper usage of reflexive pronouns are not commonly touched on by most people and because language in general is just full of loopholes in my opinion. However, as much as possible, I would like to avoid having to cite any sources or note any rules whenever I construct sentences like this or rephrase them into a different voice: "The boy was told different things about himself by the man."

Comment: Regardless of 'rules', common sense should tell you that if a sentence is ambiguous it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: I'd only use "The man told the boy different things about him." after say "A tall sandy-haired man came and stood next to the boy, and pointed to Stan." //  "The man told the boy different things about himself [the boy]." disambiguates but is clumsy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But, what I would really like to know is whether a reflexive pronoun, such as "himself," can refer to either the subject or another object in a clause or not, despite causing any ambiguity.

Comment: If it can cause ambiguity, it must have at least a dual role. But your 'rule' is inadequate. Would you consider 'I've seen the boss himself, and we're still not using the correct grade of glass' incorrect?

Comment: Maybe you want it to be ambiguous? "The man told me many things about himself" and "the man told me many things about myself" are not ambiguous, but your sentence is, because "himself" can refer either to the man or boy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, if I'm not mistaken, the function of "himself" in your example is that of an intensive pronoun, which, based from what I know, is different from a reflexive pronoun.

Comment: @Xanne, why would I want it to be ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, but the words are intercategorial polysemes ('himself' in both cases).  '"The man mentioned to the boy some rather unpleasant things about himself." would normally be the reflexive usage, but one assumes _not_ after "The boy provided the man with a list of faults the girl all too obviously possessed."  _You_ make the assumption that  'himself' must be reflexive here.

Answer (score 1):

The man is the 'subject' of the sentence, so is presumably referring to himself.  If you wanted it to be about the boy then you could say something like 'The man told the boy some things he knew about him'